# Planner Tasks: Set "OrderHint" with no effect (Graph API)

Tags: .net, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to reorder some tasks in the Planner with the Graph API.

I think, I can set the OrderHint, but this has no effect on the Planner GUI.
The tasks are still sorted as before.

For example:
I have 3 tasks.

```
Task 1 OrderHint: 8586798945610164343P9
Task 2 OrderHint: 858679899904C
Task 3 OrderHint: [m
```

I updated Task 3 OrderHint successfully to 858679896p

The order should be now:

```
Task 1 OrderHint: 8586798945610164343P9
Task 3 OrderHint: 858679896p
Task 2 OrderHint: 858679899904C
```

But this has no effect on the planner.
The Order is still:

```
Task 1
Task 2
Task 3
```

I have read https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/planner_order_hint_format

> The client can obtain the values immediate if return=representation preference is specified in the PATCH requests.

Maybe this is the solution, but I dont know how to set return=representation in the path request.

I tried already to add a header "return" : "representation"

Have you any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution: use planner/tasks/bucketTaskBoardFormat OrderHint to order the tasks in planner web gui

Comment: That is correct. OrderHint property on task is an ordering of the task in a flat list of tasks in the plan. Planner UI currently doesn't have this view. Each different way to order a task (i.e. in different views) is determined by a different orderHint property.